# how to save all CLlocations\CLLocationCoordinate2D into an array

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase, cllocation, cllocationcoordinate2d

Im retrieving all Annotation locations from my firebase database. Code below (which only runs after a new Child is added into the database)

```
var ILocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D()
let manager = CLLocationManager()
var UserName = String()
var C1 = CLLocation()

func allLocationAnnotations() {
        let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

        databaseRef.child("Locations").queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
            let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
            let longitude = value?["Longitude"] as! String
            let latitude = value?["Latitude"] as! String
            let name = value?["Location Shared By"] as! String
            let annotationCityName = value?["Annotation_City"] as! String

            self.allAnnotationLocations.insert(annotationStruct(Longitude: longitude, Latitude: latitude), at: 0)
//            print("\(name) - Location of Longitude \(longitude), Latitude: \(latitude)")

            let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()

            annotation.title = "\(name)"
            annotation.subtitle = "around this location"

            annotation.coordinate.latitude = Double(latitude)!
            annotation.coordinate.longitude = Double(longitude)!
            self.map.addAnnotation(annotation)
            self.addRadiusCircle(location: annotation)

            self.TotalInUserCity += 1
            self.SpottedNum.text = "\(self.TotalInUserCity)"

            self.C1 = CLLocation(latitude: Double(latitude)!, longitude: Double(longitude)!)
        })
    }
```

I then Use this locationManager to get users location

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let location = locations[0]
        let myLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude)
        ILocation = myLocation
        self.map.showsTraffic = true
        self.map.isZoomEnabled = true
        self.map.showsUserLocation = true

        let span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.1, 0.1)
        let region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(myLocation, span)
        map.setRegion(region, animated: true)

        geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler: { placemarks, error in
            guard let addressDict = placemarks?[0].addressDictionary else {
                return
            }

            if let city = addressDict["City"] as? String {
                self.CityLocation.text = "\(city)"
//                print("City is: \(city)")
            }
        })
```

Code below is in same locationManager function -- Then Right Below in this code I'm trying to grab all the locations to see if my users current location is near any of the anootations no matter how many.  but instead I'm only getting one annotation location because when i store it in the var C1 above it can only hold one value which I'm aware of but when i try to create an array and hold them inside I get errors like can't Convert Cllocation to CLLocationCoordinate2D :( thanks for the help in advance

```
    let C2 = CLLocation(latitude: Double(self.ILocation.latitude), longitude: Double(self.ILocation.longitude))

    let distanceInMeters = C1.distance(from: C2) // result is in meters

    if(distanceInMeters <= 1609)
    {
        print("Your are close to a Location Shared by:---------------")
    }
    else
    {
        // out of 1 mile
    }
}
```

Here is Code in One piece

```
    var ILocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D()
    let manager = CLLocationManager()
    var UserName = String()
    var C1 = CLLocation()

    func allLocationAnnotations() {
            let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

            databaseRef.child("Locations").queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
                let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
                let longitude = value?["Longitude"] as! String
                let latitude = value?["Latitude"] as! String
                let name = value?["Location Shared By"] as! String
                let annotationCityName = value?["Annotation_City"] as! String

                self.allAnnotationLocations.insert(annotationStruct(Longitude: longitude, Latitude: latitude), at: 0)
    //            print("\(name) - Location of Longitude \(longitude), Latitude: \(latitude)")

                let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()

                annotation.title = "\(name)"
                annotation.subtitle = "around this location"

                annotation.coordinate.latitude = Double(latitude)!
                annotation.coordinate.longitude = Double(longitude)!
                self.map.addAnnotation(annotation)
                self.addRadiusCircle(location: annotation)

                self.TotalInUserCity += 1
                self.SpottedNum.text = "\(self.TotalInUserCity)"

                self.C1 = CLLocation(latitude: Double(latitude)!, longitude: Double(longitude)!)
            })
        }

 func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
            let location = locations[0]
            let myLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude)
            ILocation = myLocation
            self.map.showsTraffic = true
            self.map.isZoomEnabled = true
            self.map.showsUserLocation = true

            let span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.1, 0.1)
            let region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(myLocation, span)
            map.setRegion(region, animated: true)

            geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler: { placemarks, error in
                guard let addressDict = placemarks?[0].addressDictionary else {
                    return
                }

                if let city = addressDict["City"] as? String {
                    self.CityLocation.text = "\(city)"
    //                print("City is: \(city)")
                }
            })

        let C2 = CLLocation(latitude:   Double(self.ILocation.latitude), longitude: Double(self.ILocation.longitude))

        let distanceInMeters = C1.distance(from: C2) // result is in meters

        if(distanceInMeters <= 1609)
        {
            print("Your are close to a Location Shared by:---------------")
        }
        else
        {
            // out of 1 mile
        }
    }
```

Also When I try to append I only get one annotation location as before.  Thank you again hope you can help :)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting only one Annotation because , your method `allLocationAnnotations()` being called only once .

When the location updates the only method which calls every time is

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

}
```

so just call your method `allLocationAnnotations()` in the above method . 
All the best .

Comment: Thank you for that advice :), but since the code that is grabbing the data from my firebase which is databaseRef.child("Ice_Locations").queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) is in that function is works as a loop and runs as many times as the total of children there are in my firebase database an also runs whenever a new child is added in the database.  Firebase works as a realtime Database. So basically if i add it into that function it loops through forever